# Meaning of idiom

Tags: idioms

“I have long been of the opinion that if work were such a splendid thing the rich would have kept more of it for themselves"
please help me explain this sentence. Many thanks

Comment: There is no idiom here to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have long been of the opinion that..." means "I have held the opinion I am about to describe for a long time"

"if work were such a splendid thing" means "if work was as good a thing as people tell me it is"

"the rich would have kept more of it for themselves" means "rich people would do more of it instead of leaving it for poor people to do"

Does that help?

The intention is satirical or, more probably, sarcastic. It is certainly humorous.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [*epigram*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigram), attributed to [Bruce Grocott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Grocott,_Baron_Grocott). It is a comment on the hypocrisy of many rich people who praise the virtue of hard work whilst doing none themselves. As has already been pointed out, it contains no idiomatic English (that I can see).

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for something like "If the good Lord had intended me to fly he would have given me wings". But I can't think of anything, I'm afraid.

Comment: @WS2 ... or as a friend once commented on my liking for good food: "If pigs could fly, you'd be a squadron leader."